# Conversion of UTF-8 char to ISO-8859-1

Tags: java, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have tried to convert UTF8 char to ISO-8859-1 but all characters (like 0x84; 0x96;) are not converting into ISO-8859-1, See code below in java

```
    static byte[] encode(byte[] arr) throws CharacterCodingException{
           Charset utf8charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
           Charset iso88591charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");    
           ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap( arr );    
            // decode UTF-8
           CharBuffer data = utf8charset.decode(inputBuffer);    
           // encode ISO-8559-1
            ByteBuffer outputBuffer=  iso88591charset.newEncoder()
                .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
                .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
                .encode(data); 
           data = iso88591charset.decode(outputBuffer);
           byte[] outputData = outputBuffer.array();    

           return outputData;
    }
```

Please help to resolve it.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure these characters exist at all in ISO-8859-1? Its wikipedia page says not all languages' characters are supported. You'll have to find a way to map the missing characters to simpler ones, e.g. without accents.

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a go,

```
    String str = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF-8");

    byte[] isoBytes = str.getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" );
```

If it gives you exactly the same result, then you have characters that do not map between those character sets.

Comment: if i would use Report instead Replace than it throws Unmappable exception which shows characters are unmappble.                                                               // encode ISO-8559-1
            ByteBuffer outputBuffer=  iso88591charset.newEncoder()
                .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
                .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
                .encode(data);

Answer (score 0):

First you might use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` and `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1`.

However, better replace `"ISO-8859-1"` with `"Windows-1252"`.

The reason is that browsers and others interprete an indication of ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) as Windows-1252 (Windows Latin-1). In Windows Latin-1 the range 0x80 - 0xbf are used for comma-like quotes and such.

So with a bit of luck (I do not think you meant browsers) this will work.

BTW in browsers this will even work on the Mac, and is official since HTML5.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i have tried this and did not work. Its a desktop portal application.

Comment: But look here [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) - no 0x84, 0x96. And [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) - 0x84 `„` and 0x96 `–`.

Comment: yeah those Windows-1252 chars has to be filetered out or i should get some exception. I tried to get exception using encoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT) which is throwing as there is no mappable character.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you say "0x84, 0x96" you mean bytes in the byte array.
If that is the case, you are taking those bytes and try to interpret them as UTF-8, but
that sequence of bytes is not a valid UTF-8 sequence.

```
from U+0000  to U+007F   : 1 byte  :  0xxxxxxx
from U+0080  to U+07FF   : 2 bytes :  110xxxxx  10xxxxxx
from U+0800  to U+FFFF   : 3 bytes :  1110xxxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx
from U+10000 to U+1FFFFF : 4 bytes :  11110xxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx
```

Since 84 96 is 0x10000100 0x10010110 is does not match the bit patterns above
(note the 0x11.... or 0x0.... in the lead byte, never 0x10...., that is a "trailing byte")